# SQL Sum() with correlated subquery

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery

I have two tables: fund and items. Items has a field called fundID that is related to the ID of the fund table. Items also has a price field.

Here's a simplified example of the two tables:

```
FUND
ID    fundName
1     maintenance
2     books
3     development
4     media


ITEMS
ID    price    fundID
1     $10        2
2     $20        4
3     $5         4
4     $8         1
5     $10        3
6     $12        4
```

I want to create a query that will give me the name of each fund and the sum of all prices for items that are connected to that fund through the fundID field. I have tried several methods such as having a correlated subquery within the SUM() and also within the WHERE, and I am getting errors.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: sql server?  my sql? oracle? version ?  It always helps:-)

Comment: Actually SharePoint 2010 lists with an Access front-end. The actual SQL server is MS SQL (not sure which version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT f.fundname,
       SUM(i.price)
FROM   fund f
       JOIN items i
         ON i.fundid = f.id
GROUP  BY f.fundname
```

Comment: Why does it stop working when I enter more fields into the SELECT part of the code? For instance, f.fundCode and fund.fundCode both throw different error messages.

Comment: @penco you cannot add fields which result in ambiguity with the group by... if you explain your table structure (fundCode ?) then i can guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

There's no good reason to do it this way given your table structure  however the question does ask about a sub query and the table structure is simplified.

So this will give the same results as straightfoward JOIN/GROUP BY

```
SELECT f.fundname, 
       coalesce(i.price,0) price
FROM   fund f 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT fundid, 
                          SUM(price) price 
                   FROM   items i 
                   GROUP  BY fundid) i 
         ON f.fundid = i.fundid
```

Note the COALESCE/LEFT JOIN is there in case you want 0 for funds that have no items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select fundName,sum(price) as  TotPrice
from Funds f
join Items g on g.id=f.id
group by f.fundName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT f.fundid, f.fundName, SUM(price)
FROM Fund f 
   INNER JOIN ITEMS i ON i.fundId = f.fundId
GROUP BY f.FUNDID
```

If you have a lot of funds fund Id is probably better to group by